# Could plasma "blow away" bullets?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, electromagnetism

I have a shield concept, however, I'm not entirely sure, if it's capable of stopping bullets.

The basic concept is an enhanced version of [Boeing's patent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOmUhjlfh1o), that:

1. The system ionizes a small portion of air in front of the bullet.
2. Then a magnetic field expands the plasma outwards.

So, **this plasma explosion should have more power than the explosion used to launch the bullet.**

Precision is NOT a concern.

Would this be achievable with a plasma explosion?

Energy is not really a problem.

Comment: You asked this same question yourself yesterday.

Comment: [Plasma Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_window#Similarity_to_.22force_fields.22)

Comment: @sphennings Negative, that one was asked about the preciseness of the system, not its power.

Comment: What patent? Gib links, at least to wiki.

Comment: Both questions are asking "Is it possible to deflect projectiles using plasma?" If you feel that this question is distinct please edit the question to highlight how it differs.

Comment: Could you maybe edit in your calculations concerning required field strength and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more complicated than stopping the bullet with an identical bullet of the same but opposite speed. Your plasma will not stick to the bullet, so it must vaporize it. You would need energy equal to the kinetic energy of the bullet, plus the heat needed to melt and vaporize it, plus the energy lost because your plasma would go around the bullet.

Comment: So, setting off multiple explosions?

Comment: No, just one beam of plasma which is hot enough and focused enough. You could have colder plasma confined with electromagnetic field, and when the guy shoots you could discharge a lot of energy to make your plasma hotter in order to meet the bullet.